# Error compiling proxmark3 fork from peter fillmore

Tags: c++, git, qt, arm

I desperately try to compile [Peter Fillmore's fork from github](https://github.com/peterfillmore/proxmark3.git).

Other forks compile fine on the same machine/OS, but can't find the error by comparing Makefiles etc.
Others have similar problems but can't find the answer either.

I get the FW compiled but the client compilation gives me this error:

```
in file included from proxmark3.h:16:0, from proxmark3.c:20:
/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/inttypes.h:290:8: error: unknown type name ‘intmax_t’
 extern intmax_t imaxabs (intmax_t __n) __THROW __attribute__ ((__const__));
        ^~~~~~~~
/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/inttypes.h:290:26: error: unknown type name ‘intmax_t’
 extern intmax_t imaxabs (intmax_t __n) __THROW __attribute__ ((__const__));
                          ^~~~~~~~
/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/inttypes.h:293:27: error: unknown type name ‘intmax_t’
 extern imaxdiv_t imaxdiv (intmax_t __numer, intmax_t __denom)
                           ^~~~~~~~
/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/inttypes.h:293:45: error: unknown type name ‘intmax_t’
 extern imaxdiv_t imaxdiv (intmax_t __numer, intmax_t __denom)
                                             ^~~~~~~~
/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/inttypes.h:297:8: error: unknown type name ‘intmax_t’
 extern intmax_t strtoimax (const char *__restrict __nptr,
        ^~~~~~~~
/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/inttypes.h:301:8: error: unknown type name ‘uintmax_t’
 extern uintmax_t strtoumax (const char *__restrict __nptr,
        ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/inttypes.h:305:8: error: unknown type name ‘intmax_t’
 extern intmax_t wcstoimax (const __gwchar_t *__restrict __nptr,
        ^~~~~~~~
/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/inttypes.h:310:8: error: unknown type name ‘uintmax_t’
 extern uintmax_t wcstoumax (const __gwchar_t *__restrict __nptr,
```

I have tried many things, but I can't get it to work.

To be more specific: I tried it on different OS's, i.e. Kali liniux (debian) and Win8/10. All gave me the same error.

I posted the question also here: http://proxmark.org/forum/viewtopic.php?id=3898.

I tried to point to another `<inttypes.h>` but get similar errors. If I remove it I get this errors

> In file included from /usr/include/newlib/sys/types.h:63:0, from /usr/include/newlib/stdio.h:48, from optimized_cipher.c:64: /usr/include/newlib/sys/_stdint.h:31:19: error: conflicting types for 'int32_t' typedef __int32_t int32_t ;

and so on

Comment: to be more specific: tried on different OS's. Kali liniux (debian), Win8/10. All gave me the same error. Posted also here: http://www.proxmark.org/forum/viewtopic.php?id=3898. I tried to point to another <inttypes.h> but get similar erros and if i remove it i get this errors <code> In file included from /usr/include/newlib/sys/types.h:63:0,
                 from /usr/include/newlib/stdio.h:48,
                 from optimized_cipher.c:64:
/usr/include/newlib/sys/_stdint.h:31:19: error: conflicting types for 'int32_t'
 typedef __int32_t int32_t ; </code> and so on

Answer (score 0):

One solution seems to be to remove the stdint.h from the /include directory.
After that some formatting errors have to be corrected, and it compile.